# -[UITableView _setupTableViewCommon] erroe for iphone simulator logs

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, uitableview, crash

Please get it resolved , I am getting this error when i am running amy app in iphone simulator

> Single stepping until exit from function -[UITableView
>   _setupTableViewCommon]

and App crashes at `[window makeKeyAndVisible];`

but the code is working fine on the device.